# Using controller attribute and isolated scope in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I have angular directive that displays few elements defined in compile like this(only one button in this example):

```
compile: function(element, attrs) {
        var htmlText = '<button ng-click='myFunction()'></button>';
        element.replaceWith(htmlText);
        return linkF;
    },
```

where linkF is a link function:

```
var linkF = function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $scope.$element = $element;
};
```

This way I can access element in controller anf modify it.

I have my controller defined in controller parameter of directive.

```
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.myFunction = function() {
        //some code to mofify $scope.$element
      }
```

Now my question is how to use isolated scope with this solution(need to reuse component on page few times), because if I define

```
scope: {},
```

then myFunction stops firing on button click.

I know I am doing some basic thing wrong but I cant figure it out, please help.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/N9jQ8uMpxU5o6IVZThaJ?p=preview this is how it is usually done. Dont use controller for work with DOM, use link instead.

Comment: Thanks for tip! But this doesnt solve my problem, because I need to use controller anyway for other logic(api calls etc)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/N9jQ8uMpxU5o6IVZThaJ?p=preview you can combine them if u want. I just told that storing link to element in controller is bad idea). As I saw using of link is more common than use of controller.